# Intro.js Guide number is slightly displaced

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, intro.js

I have incorporated Intro.js for implementing guide in my website.
Although it is working perfectly fine what i have problem with is small integer number displaying on top left corner of the div selected for guide. (Picture attached)

[image]

This number is slightly displaced from where it should be.
Please tell me how to reposition it in the centre or better tell me how can i get rid of it i.e no number at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to your CSS:

```
.introjs-helperNumberLayer{ display:none; }
```

I imagine something is conflicting with your CSS to cause that problem, or its a browser specific issue. In any case, you'll need to post a JSbin or similar to let us see the code.